# How to delete row x from a cvs using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have been working on a script to make a website list but i struggle with removing a selected option from the table.

I'm using a function for this and it goes as follows:

```sh
function Open-WebsiteList{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="The action you want to do open/start/add/remove.")]
        [string]$action,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,HelpMessage="The details for the action.")]
        $detail,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,HelpMessage="The url if you wish to add.")]
        [string]$url
    )
    $csv = Import-Csv "C:\Eclips-Terminal\Files\Websites.csv"
    $title = "Open-WebsiteList" + $action + " " + $detail + " " + $url
    if ($action -eq "open"){
        $csv | Format-Table
    }elseif ($action -eq "start"){
        $detail -= 1
        $csv_url= $csv | select "url" | select -Skip $detail | Select-Object -first 1
        $csv_url = $csv_url -split "`r`n"; $csv_url = $csv_url.substring(6); $csv_url = $csv_url.Substring(0,$csv_url.Length-1)
        Start-Website $csv_url
    }elseif ($action -eq "add"){
    
    }elseif ($action -eq "remove"){
    
    }else{
        Invoke-BalloonTip -Message "Please make sure all options are valid" -Title $title -MessageType Warning 
    }
}
```

(the invoke-balloontip is a function to make the popups in the bottem right easyer.)

This script then gives me the following table:

```
number name            url                        
------ ----            ---                        
1      google          www.google.com             
2      youtube         www.youtube.com            
3      gmail           www.gmail.com              
4      stackoverflow   www.stackoverflow.com      
5      Eclips-Terminal www.tiny.one/eclips-terinal
```

(please dont visit my website its trash)

To sum it up:

- You get the number of the row to delete.
- Delete that row.
- Done

Also the adding part is not in the code but i know a way to do it so dont worrie about it.
(And to ppl who say "You need to show what you tried." why would i save everything that didnt do what i want it to do?)

Comment: Try filterint the CSV with `| ? { $_.someproperty -notlike "*unwanted*" }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @vonPryz for giving me this idea.

I fixed the issue using:

```sh
$detail = 6
$csv = ""
$csv = import-csv C:\Eclips-Terminal\Files\Websites.csv
$csv | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch $detail}|export-csv C:\Eclips-terminal\Files\Websites.csv -Force
```

It will work for what i need but if any know how to only check the numbers column please comment so it will work in general.

Edit:
Thanks to @zett42 i now have a actual universal version wich also lets users enter numbers in the names and updates the numbers to be correct again.

```sh
$raw_csv = ""
$csv_raw = ""
$csv = ""
$new_raw_csv = ""
$cnt = ""
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Eclips-Terminal\Files\Websites.csv"
[array]$raw_csv = Get-Content C:\Eclips-Terminal\Files\Websites.csv | select-object -skip 2
$detail = 5
$csv | Where-Object number -ne $detail | export-csv C:\Eclips-terminal\Files\Websites.csv -Force
$cnt = 0
foreach ($line in $raw_csv){
$line = $line.substring(2) 
$cnt += 1
[array]$new_raw_csv += '"' + $cnt + $line
}
$new_raw_csv | Out-File C:\Eclips-Terminal\Files\Websites.csv
```

Comment: `$csv | Where-Object number -ne $detail | ...`